# How to use an authenticated user with S3 and AWS-SDK in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am following the following example:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
    :access_key_id => "something",
    :secret_access_key => "verysecret",
    :region => 'us-east-1')


bucket = s3.bucket('mybucket').object('test')
bucket.upload_file('/files/useless.txt')
```

I am getting this terrible "Access Denied" error, and that's most likely because I am not being the authenticated user I need to be - and missing in this code. Where do I fit it in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access_key_id and secret_access_key are user specific. If you go to the AWS console and go to the IAM tools, you can set up new keys.